# Open iTunes from an UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

How can I open the iTunes App Store from an UIWebView? what code (javascript?) should i use?

Comment: Maybe this helps you:
[OS X Yosemite Javascript for Automation and iTunes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711618/os-x-yosemite-javascript-for-automation-and-itunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/01/itunes-deep-links-demystified-how-to.html