# OS X Yosemite Javascript for Automation and iTunes

Tags: javascript, automation, itunes, osx-yosemite, javascript-automation

I'm trying to click on button "Free" to download application in iTunes.
I'm using Javascript for Automation to open iTunes application page:

```
itunes = Application('iTunes');
itunes.activate();
console.log( itunes.name() );
console.log( itunes.version() );
delay(1)
appUrl = "itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8";
win = itunes.openLocation(appUrl);
```

The script opens iBook page. How to find and click button "Free"?
How to list all elements on open page?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the script editor, the library for the Itunes Application, i didn't found any method or object dealing with books in the itunes store. So i think, it's a dead end. The iBooks application is not scriptable anyway.

However to go ahead with your problem, clicking the [Free] button :

```
appUrl = "itms://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?genreId=38&popId=42";
win = itunes.openLocation(appUrl);
```

The URL targeted by the **[Free]** button could be found by browsing books in iTunes, in the right side of the interface ( "Free books", right-clic => Copy the link ). Perhaps the URL is different for your US version but you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I need to programmatically click a [Get] button (see screenshot: http://i58.tinypic.com/30wme1d.png). It is located below iBooks logo. It has changed in last version on iTunes.